# How to Convert the code to list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Below is a working Code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input("Enter x: "))
    y = int(input("Enter y: "))
    z = int(input("Enter z: "))
    n = int(input("Enter n: "))
    ar=[]
    p=0


for i in range ( x + 1 ) :
    for j in range( y + 1):
        for k in range( z + 1):
            if i+j+k != n:
                ar.append([])
                ar[p] = [i, j, k]
                p+=1
                print(ar[-1], end=" ")
```

input:

```
x=1
y=1
z=1
n=2
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 1] [0, 1, 0] [1, 0, 0] [1, 1, 1]
```

My Requirement is to convert it to List Comprehensive method as below:

```
[print ([x, y, z]) for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if ( (i + j + k ) != n )]
```

Comment: Note you can get the same result with `[t for t in itertools.product(range(x + 1), range(y + 1), range(z + 1)) if sum(t) != n]`.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Why do you have a "requirement" for a list comprehension? Also, using `print()` is a side-effect because you'll get a list of `None`; that's considered an anti-pattern. Or, perhaps that's the problem you're actually encountering.

Comment: I'm confused: (1) You have a "requirement" for a list comprehension -- however, this isn't labeled as homework; (2) You present a solution, and you haven't shown any problem.  This doesn't appear to be a question.

Comment: Putting `print` out of the comprehension seems like it would be what you want - but your question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This part is way too complicated for what you want to do:

```
ar.append([])
ar[p] = [i, j, k]
p+=1
```

The correct way to do it is:

```
ar.append([i, j, k])
```

And for the comprehension... that is easy, to turn this into a comprehension:

```
result = []
for XXXX:
    for YYYY:
        if ZZZZ:
            for QQQQ:
                result.append(RRRR)
```

simply do:

```
result = [RRRR for XXXX for YYYY if ZZZZ for QQQQ]
```

So, in your case:

```
ar = [[i, j, k]
      for i in range ( x + 1 )
          for j in range( y + 1)
              for k in range( z + 1)
                  if i+j+k != n]
```